# Is infinite-dimensional complexification isomorphic to real vector space from which it came?

Tags: vector-spaces

In finite-dimensions, the complexification of a real vector space is easily shown to be isomorphic to the original real space by using a proof which involves explicit use of a finite basis. Does the result also hold for infinite-dimensional spaces?

Comment: What do you mean by "isomorphic to the original real space"? As a real vector space it has twice the dimension. This *is* true in infinite dimensions but not canonically and iirc requires the axiom of choice.

Comment: Take real vector space $\mathbb R$, its complexification is $\mathbb C$ - how is it isomorphic to $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Perhaps I didn't understand my text, but don't we have $\dim_\mathbb{R} V = \dim_\mathbb{C} V^C$? Now that I think about it, this is not enough for isomorphism in the vector spaces sense (since the scalar fields are different), but I guess I'm wondering if that relationship also holds with suitable generalization in infinite dimensions.

Comment: @mihaild Please see above.

Comment: So, you are interested in dimension (cardinality of basis), not isomorphism?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You are right, it was my mistake to go so far as to say isomorphism (I am used to the equal dimension means isomorphism, but of course that only holds over the same field of scalars). @mihaild

Comment: Yes, they always have the same dimension, and in fact the complexification of a basis of a real vector space is always a (complex) basis of its complexification.

Comment: Yes, that is how I did the dimension proof in finite-dimensions. But I wasn't sure I could use the same argument in infinite-dimensions...as you say, I suppose it involves Choice? @QiaochuYuan

Comment: If you have basis of real space, it is basis of its complexification, even without AC. But I am not sure if you can go in the other direction, even is it true that if complexification has a basis, then original space has one too.